# RxJava operator that combines two observables and emits only when the first observable emits

Tags: android, rx-java

I am new to `RxJava` and I am stuck with finding a right operator. 
I want to have something like `combineLatest`, but only emit event when the first `Observable` emits an item and take the last item from the second `Observable`.
I am  currently doing so using `BehaviourSubject`, but I would like to avoid having external variable if there is operator doing such thing.

What I have now:

```
        BehaviorSubject<Login> inputSubject = BehaviorSubject.create();
    Observable.
            combineLatest(
                    RxTextView.textChanges(inputEmail.getEditText()),
                    RxTextView.textChanges(inputPassword.getEditText()),
                    Login::new)
            .subscribe(inputSubject);
    return RxView.clicks(loginBtn).map(v -> inputSubject.getValue());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a second `combineLatest`:

```
Observable<Void> clicks = RxView.clicks(loginBtn);
Observable<Login> loginData = ...

class TaggedLogin {
    Object tag;
    Login data;

    TaggedLogin(Object tag, Login data) {
        this.tag = tag;
        this.data = data;
    }
}

return Observable.combineLatest(
    clicks.map(v -> new Object()), 
    loginData, 
    TaggedLogin::new
).distinctUntilChanged(tl -> tl.tag).map(tl -> tl.data);
```

The juggling with the tag is required because combineLatest will emit if either has a new value.

If you're willing to use `Experimental` features (aka RxJava might remove or change them in the future) then the following is possible:

```
Observable<Void> clicks = RxView.clicks(loginBtn);
Observable<Login> loginData = ...

return clicks.withLatestFrom(loginData, (v, data) -> data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the last operator on the second observable and use zip to combine them.

Comment: But the second observable does not call onComplete() so the last() operator would not emit anything

Comment: So you need to rephrase your question, as you said "take the last item from the second Observable". If there is no onComplete call, what does the last item mean ?